# Passing JSON data in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Greetings I have this statement that takes my array of results and echo's it out to display on my AJAX form using json_encode, however now I want to pass the array as $data over to my Templatebuilder function since i'll be using the search as part of a bigger template. This is the error i'm getting, for my ajax search. **Undefined Variable: Results in ajax_search.php**

This is all done within one controller.

```
if ( $this->input-> is_ajax_request())
    {
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        $this->output->set_header("Expires:Mon, 4 Apr 1994 04:44:44 GMT");
        $this->output->set_header("Content-type:application/json");

        echo json_encode($results);

    }
```

Then I wish to send the data to my templatebuilder with this statement:

```
 echo $this->Templatebuilder('master', $data);
```

### this is my templatebuilder function

```
private function Templatebuilder ($view, $data) {
 $master_data['page1'] = $this->load->view('page1', $data, true);
 $master_data['ajax_search'] = $this->load->view('ajax_search',  $data, true);
 return $this->load->view('master', $master_data, true);
```

and finally my ajax_search page

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>">
    <fieldset>
    <label for = "search"> Seachss Query:</label>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search!" />

    </fieldset>

        <fieldset id= "results">
            <?php if (isset($results) AND count($results) ); ?>
            <ul>

                <?php foreach ($results as $result); ?>

                    <li>
                    <span class="Course_Name"> <?php echo $result['course_name_highlighted']; ?> </span> &ndash;
                    <span class="First_Name"> <?php echo $result['FirstName']; ?> </span> 
                    <span class="Last_Name"> <?php echo $result['LastName']; ?> </span> &ndash;
                    <span class="Course_ID"> <?php echo $result['COURSE_ID']; ?> </span> &ndash;
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Course" />


                    </li>



            </ul>


            </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: where do you pass `$results` variable?

Comment: I tried doing  **$data = json_encode($results);** but that didn't work

Comment: Where do you pass `$results` variable to the view file, as if I understand it's the file that throws this error

Answer (score 0):

Add [exit()](http://uk.php.net/exit):

```
echo json_encode($results);
exit(); // add exit
```

Comment: that actually works in displaying the results from the drop-down which was part of the problem . However it's still trying to return the results before I search for anything and giving me the "undefined variable" error.